# Solution for checking if exception is thrown and not exiting the script

Tags: python

I have a python script that does some GUI test on a chromium application. Sometimes this application does not load up correctly and for this reason the GUI test will not pass, but a simple restart of this application can fix the problem.

What I currently have is something like this:

```
def test():
    ...do some settings...
    ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
    ...Login(My.PinCode)...
    ...GoToDeviceUI()...
    ...undo settings...
    ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
```

When doing this login, in case the app did not load correctly an exception is thrown and my test is failing.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
def test():
   def testBody():
      ...do some settings...
      ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
      ...Login(My.PinCode)...
      ...GoToDeviceUI()...
      ...undo settings...
      ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
   try_cnt = 3
   for i in range(try_cnt):
      try:
         testBody()
         break
      except:
         ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
```

But without using a for/while loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this solve your task? You can just loop for a certain amount of time, if you get success just break.

```
def test():
   def testBody():
      ...do some settings...
      ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
      ...Login(My.PinCode)...
      ...GoToDeviceUI()...
      ...undo settings...
      ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
   try_cnt = 3
   for i in range(try_cnt):
      try:
         testBody()
         break
      except:
         ...SystemOperator.restartController()...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to execute this code only 2 times, your problem is not in this part of your code. You have to check after 2 times, if you pass in this code, or if the exception is not raise in another part of your code after 2 times